# GoLang-Undefined canvas-Need to draw to server

Tags: canvas, svg, go, webserver, drawing

I am trying to draw to a webserver using this:
The basics is that when I run it gives error "undefined: canvas". I believe its because the "canvas = svg.New(w)" is located within the "func draw()" and there are other calls of the canvas in "func sqre ()" and other functions similiar "TRI()" "CIR()" etc.. How can I fix this?

```
func sqre(){ //Square Function

var xcoord =100
    var ycoord =150

canvas.Rect(xcoord, ycoord, 250,150,"fill:none ;stroke:blue")

func draw(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {  //handler function

 w.header().Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")
  canvas = svg.New(w)

canvas.Start(width,height)


var x int
for x=0; stringarray[x] != "finish"; { 
    switch stringarray[x] {
        case "SQR":
                    Sqre() 
                    x=x+1

        case "TRI":
                    Tri()
                    x=x+1
        case "GRID":
                    Grid()
                    x=x+1
        case "FILL":
                    Filler()
                    x=x+1
        case "CIR":
                    Cir()
                    x=x+1
        default:
                x=x+1

    }

}
canvas.End()

}
func main(){


   http.Handle ("/draw",http.Handlerfunc(draw))
   err := http.ListenAndServe(":2014", nil)
     if err !=nil{
     log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
   }
}
```

Comment: The `Sqre` and related functions need to have the canvas instance passed into them as a parameter. E.g.: call `Sqre(canvas)` instead of `Sqre()`. Note that these functions will need to have their signatures redefined to accept this parameter.

Comment: can I not have "canvas" as a global variable in instances when using "stdOut"                                                     canvas = svg.New(os.Stdout)

Comment: @ElmoHuitz: not if you ever accept more than one connection at a time. Just pass the canvas to the functions that need it.